# Table with multirows, missing right vertical line

Tags: tables, multirow, tabu

I'm very new to latex and I'm trying to create a table with a combined row

[image: Table1]

As you can see, the combined row is missing the right vertical line, and I'm not able to see the problem myself.
The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to 1\textwidth { | X[l] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Table 5. Cycling protocol }} \\ 
\hline \hline
\textbf{Step} & \textbf{Temperature} & \textbf{Duration} & \textbf{Cycles}\\
\hline
Initial Denaturation & 95\degree C & 3 minutes & 1x\\
\hline
Denaturation & 95\degree C & 30 seconds & \multirow{3}{1em}{35x}\\
Annealing & 53\degree C & 30 seconds  \\
Extension & 72\degree C & 30 seconds \\
\hline
Final Extension & 72\degree C & 7 minutes& 1x\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I couldn't / didn't try (as the code snippet is not a MWE) but what happens when you add a & before the \\ of the "Annealing" and "Extension" line.

Comment: (i) always provide complete small document begining with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}, which show your problem and which we can copy in compile. (ii) in two rows below `\multirow` are missed ampersands, consequently table is not proper terminated and has missed right border line. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Albert: sorry i don't know what MWE is, but it worked, thanks!

Comment: your mwe (minimal working example, a small but complete document) is still not complete. how are defined `degree`?  also is mised `\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry Zarko! I'll try again

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

as i mentioned in my comment, each row should be proper terminated, i.e.: number of ampersands has to be equal to number of columns in this row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu} to 1\textwidth { | X[l] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Table 5. Cycling protocol }} \\
\hline \hline
\textbf{Step} & \textbf{Temperature} & \textbf{Duration} & \textbf{Cycles}      \\
\hline
Initial Denaturation
                & \SI{95}{\celsius} & 3 minutes         & 1x                    \\
\hline
Denaturation    & \SI{95}{\celsius} & \SI{30}{seconds}  & \multirow{3}{1em}{35x}\\
Annealing       & \SI{53}{\celsius} & \SI{30}{seconds}  &                       \\ % <---
Extension       & \SI{72}{\celsius} & \SI{30}{seconds}  &                       \\ % <---
\hline
Final Extension & \SI{72}{\celsius} & \SI{7}{minutes}   & 1x                    \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

off-topic: i suggest to use `siunitx` for writing inits and to table parameter add `\tabulinesep=3pt` to make more vertical spaces in cells.